# selenium Android driver - can i run 2 tests simultaneously

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible run 2 test simultaneously in actual device? using android driver.i want to run 2 browser (test) at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think yes. Try running 2 of the emulators but make sure you change the line:

```
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

To use another port for the second emulator. eg.

```
adb forward tcp:8090 tcp:8090
```

For the second one you will have to change the constructor of AndroidDriver since it uses 8080 by default. So something like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver( new URL("http://localhost:8080/hub") );
```

Comment: is it possible in 2 real devices?

Comment: Sorry couldn't answer you for sure there, never tried it with a real device. I would assume so though since the port forwarding happens similarly on a real device too.

Comment: This  answer is INCORRECT and needs to be fixed; the real answer is below at " Dec 12 '11 at 13:19 Dima Star"

Answer (score 2):

Little corrections: 
Forwarding string should be following:

```
adb forward tcp:8090 tcp:8080
```

It is important: 1st value should be 8090 (or other selected port), 2nd value should be 8080

Code should be following:

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver( new URL("http://localhost:8090/wd/hub") );
```

Comment: So true! upvoting your answer. the other answer made me waste hours of my time in investigations; it needs to be downvoted